# MVC5 Scrips Bundles Path layout / folders

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to figure this out and not sure the correct solution in MVC5 (I am somewhat new to bundles).

Basic site out from new site wizard visual studio using bootstrap.

```
mydomain.z\
mydomain.z\Home
mydomain.z\Home\Index
mydomain.z\Home\Contact
mydomain.z\Shared\Layout.cshtml
```

My layout has the render script from the bundles. It all works fine when I am at the root index page: mydomain.z/

When you start the site it is navigating to mydomain.z/ then if you navigate to the contact view page mydomain.z/Home/Contact this is where I run into problems.

The bundle renders as /Scripts/Scripts.js for example not ../../Scripts/Scripts.js

What is the correct way to fix this pathing issue, do I have to render the scripts in every page, why not know the path from the requesting controller/page?

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Comment: Why is `/Scripts/Scripts.js` problematic for you? ASP.NET bundles will always render relative to the site root.

Comment: Well, you are correct, then I pondered what else. Looking at it logically and stepping back I reflected on some basics. I forgot to put my scripts in @section scripts
{
   <script>
       $('#myModal').modal('show')
   </script>
}

so it rendered after the includes. SMH.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Must user the @section to add scripts so it renders after the jquery include

```
@section scripts 
{ 
    <script> 
        $('#myModal').modal('show') 
    </script> 
}
```

Nothing was wrong with the paths like  Darin Dimitrov noted. I was over-thinking the problem.